# Get the positive score in a classification task by using a generative model

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I'm attempting to utilize a generative model (Llama2) for a binary classification task and aim to obtain the positive score, which represents the confidence level for the positive label.

I tried to use `compute_transition_scores` but not sure how can I get the confidence between 0-1 correctly.

Here is my current code:

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    peft_config.base_model_name_or_path,
    # quantization_config=bnb_config,
    torch_dtype='auto',
    device_map='auto',
    offload_folder="offload", offload_state_dict = True
)
pos_scores = []
input_ids = tokenizer(test_sample, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
tokens_for_summary = 1
output_tokens = input_ids.shape[1] + tokens_for_summary

outputs = model.generate(inputs=input_ids, do_sample=False, max_length=output_tokens, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id, 
                         output_scores=True, return_dict_in_generate=True)
score = float(torch.exp(model.compute_transition_scores(outputs.sequences, outputs.scores)).cpu())
        
if pred_label == 1:
   pos_scores.append(score)
elif pred_label == 0:
   pos_scores.append(-1 * score) # reverse the sign of all samples for which the prediction was 0.
```

However, I'm obtaining high values. I've considered using the sigmoid function, but I'm not entirely certain if this is the correct approach.

How should I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Which model are you trying to use? What is the ultimate purpose of the binary classification? Is there a sample input and expected output you can give? Is there a reason to use CasualLM class instead of `from transformers import AutoConfig, AutoModelForSequenceClassification`?

Comment: @alvas I'm trying to do binary classification with Llama2. Yes, there is sample input and expected output and the generative model completes one token (1 for positive label, 0 for negative)

Comment: How is `peft_config` initialized? and is there a reason you're not using `AutoModelForSequenceClassification`?

Comment: Also, can you post an example input for `test_sample`?